# Replace matches AFTER having processed the match

Tags: c#, regex

In my program I am implementing tokens to be replaced with variable values.

Such a token is **#INT[1-5]** (meaning it will get replaced with a random int between 1 and 5.

I have already written the regex to match the token: **#INT[\d+-\d+]**

However I don't know how to replace the token (after having processed the match and calculated the random number.

So far I have the following:

```
Random random = new Random();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"#INT\[\d+-\d+\]");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches("This is one of #INT[1-5] tests");
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    if (m.Success)
    {
        var ints = m.Value.Split('-').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
        int intToInsert = random.Next(ints[0], ints[1]);
        //now how do I insert the int in place of the match? 
    }
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for pointing it out, although I'm aware of that. I just initialized the random in the loop for the sake of simplicity. I have edited my code to avoid the issue though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to make use of the match evaluator with [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) and use capturing groups around the numbers in your regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"#INT\[(\d+)-(\d+)\]");
//                            ^   ^ ^   ^
var res = regex.Replace("This is one of #INT[1-5] tests", m => 
            random.Next(Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value), Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[2].Value)).ToString());
```

Results: `This is one of 2 tests`, `This is one of 3 tests`, ...

The captured texts can be accessed with `m.Groups[n].Value`.

Comment: OP may or may not need a `+ 1` on the second value.

Comment: Should be noted that an input like "#INT[4-2]" will result in an exception being thrown by `Random.Next`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It works just as wanted!

Comment: @juharr: Same issue would appear in the original code. There is no clue in the question as to how to  handle such situations. I assume there is some basic error handling in place here.